# Maximal sum of positive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I'll be grateful for any help with the foollowing question. I think the solution must be easy enough but i haven't figured it out yet.

Let a and b be positive integers such that

1) $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z}: ~~ a^2 + b^2 = c^3$

2) $\exists d \in \mathbb{Z}: ~~ a^3 + b^3 = d^2$

The task is to find the maximal possible sum of a and b.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we found such integers $a$ and $b$. Let $a_1=k^6a$, and let $b_1=k^6b$.

Then $a_1^2+b_1^2=(k^4c)^3$ and $a_1^3+b_1^3=(k^9 d)^2$.

Now note that $a=2$, $b=2$ have the property that $a^2+b^2$ is a perfect cube and $a^3+b^3$ is a perfect square.

So already by taking $k=1,2,3,\dots$, we have infinitely many examples. There is **no maximum value** for the sum $a+b$.

**Remark:** Perhaps by putting additional constraints on $a$ and $b$, we can come up with a natural problem of the same kind for which there are only finitely many solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much!

But what should i do if the task is to find a,b, such that conditions 1) and 2) hold,  $a \neq b$ and sum $a + b$ is minimal possible?

Comment: You are welcome. A variant solution is that we can take $a=2^{6d+1}$, $b=2^{6d+1}$ for any non-negative integer $d$.

Comment: @Igor: That is a different question, that I have not thought about. But the same technique applies: if you can find one solution, you can find infinitely many using the same trick.

Comment: But the numbers are positive integers (i'm sorry for not noting it in my previous comment), so any set of them has the minimal element. The main problem is that i can't find it.

Comment: The question asks for the **maximal** possible sum. Nothing to do with minimal anything. The minimal sum is of course $4$, reached at $a=b=2$.

Comment: Certainly yes if we allow a=b but what if numbers must be distinct?


1) $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, a>0, b>0$

2) $∃c∈Z:  a2+b2=c3$

3) $∃d∈Z:  a3+b3=d2$

4) $a \neq b$

5) sum $a + b$ is minimal possible

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question, specifically outlawing $a=b$. Presumably you are interested in solving the system $a^2+b^2=c^3$, $a^3+b^3=d^2$, in positive integers $a,b,c,d$ with $a\ne b$.

Comment: OK. I'll do it now.