# Cubes, squares and minimal sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, arithmetic

I have trouble solving the following task: i need to find positive integers a and b such that

1) $a \neq b$

2) $ \exists c \in \mathbb{N} : ~ a^2 + b^2 = c^3$

3) $\exists d \in \mathbb{N}: ~ a^3 + b^3 = d^2$

4) sum $a + b$ is minimal possible

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you think $0 \in \mathbb N$, then $a=0,b=1$ is minimal.  Without the restriction $a \ne b$, the minimal solution is $a=b=2, c=2, d=4$.  More generally $a=b=2^{6n+1}, c=2^{4n+1}, d=2^{9n+2}$ is a solution.

Comment: @WillJagy
The task was to find it "by hand" :)

Comment: @RossMillikan
But a = 1250 and b = 625 are also solutions and they don't have the form $2^{6n+1}$

Comment: @Igor:  True.  I found these while Jeppe Stig Nielsen was finding that one.  I had a bug in my code that wasn't a problem for the powers of $2$ but caused it to miss $625,1250$.  Again this becomes a family $2 \cdot 5^{6n+4},5^{6n+4}$

Comment: @RossMillikan More generally, in [a post that was the inspiration to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/347470/70134), André Nicolas correctly argues that whenever $(a, b)$ works, then so does $(k^6a, k^6b)$, for any $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=1250$ and $b=625$, then $a=2\cdot 5^4$ and $b=5^4$, and

$$
a^2 + b^2 = 2^2\cdot 5^8 + 5^8 = (4 + 1)5^8 = 5^9 = (5^3)^3
$$
$$
a^3 + b^3 = 2^3\cdot 5^{12} + 5^{12} = (8 + 1)5^{12} = 3^2(5^6)^2 = (3\cdot 5^6)^2
$$

This was the smallest example I found by an extremely primitive computer search.